# Need to be pointed in the right direction with my Loops code

Tags: java

newbie at Java here. My professor returned my file with this comment
"3) The program does not implement the new loop correctly.  The purpose of the loop was to allow the user to enter in their four numbers and do the math.  The program should then ask the user if they want to continue,  If they do, the program should allow the entry of four more numbers.  The should continue until the user specifically says no they want to stop.
"

I am confused about how to ask the user if they wanted to continue then allow re entry of four more numbers again.

I'm having issues on entering the proper error message as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // 1.   Declare two integer variables and two double variables  
    int iNumber;
    int iNumber2;
    double iDecimal;
    double iDecimal2;
    int count;
    char yesNo = 'y'; // When a char variable is declared, the value needs to be a char not a string. Therefore, it needs a single quote instead of a double quote.

// 2.   Instantiate a Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// 3.   Place the entry of the number into a loop that requires the user to enter the values at least one time.
    //int i = 1;

// NOTE – Steps 4 through 8 are EXACTLY the same as the CE-Decision exercise.  You may reuse that code if you would like.
// 4.   Using print, display two lines that allows the user to enter in the two integer values on the same line as the prompt.
    System.out.print("Input integer value 1: ");
    iNumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input integer value 2: ");
    iNumber2 = input.nextInt();

// 5.   Using print, display two lines that allows the user to enter in the two double values on the same line as the prompt.
    System.out.print("Input double value 1: ");
    iDecimal = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Input double value 2: ");
    iDecimal2 = input.nextDouble();

// 6.   Using multiple printf statements, display the result of adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing and moding the two integer values.

    if (iNumber > iNumber2)
    {
        System.out.println("\nNumber 1 is greater than Number 2: ");
        //+ instead of , for Printlns. , for printf. To add, use parenthesis. 
        System.out.println("\nInput integer value 1: "+ iNumber);
        System.out.println("Input integer value 2: "+ iNumber2);
        System.out.println("Input double value 1: "+ iDecimal);
        System.out.println("Input double value 2: "+ iDecimal2);

        System.out.println("\nInteger output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Adding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber + iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Subtracting ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber - iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Multiplying ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber * iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Dividing ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber / iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Moding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber % iNumber2);

        System.out.println("\nDouble output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Adding ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal + iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Subtracting ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal - iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Multiplying ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal * iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Dividing ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal / iDecimal2);          
    }

    else if (iNumber < iNumber2)
    {
        System.out.println("\nNumber 2 is greater than Number 1:");
        //+ instead of , for Printlns. , for printf. To add, use parenthesis. 
        System.out.println("\nInput integer value 1: " + iNumber);
        System.out.println("Input integer value 2: " + iNumber2);
        System.out.println("Input double value 1: " + iDecimal);
        System.out.println("Input double value 2: " + iDecimal2);

        System.out.println("\nInteger output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Adding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber + iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Subtracting ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber - iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Multiplying ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber * iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Division ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber / iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n\n", "Moding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber % iNumber2);

        System.out.println("Double output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Adding ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal + iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Subtracting ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal - iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Multiplying ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal * iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Dividing ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal / iDecimal2);

    }
    else if (iNumber2 == iNumber)
    {
        System.out.println("\nBoth numbers are equal");
        //+ instead of , for Printlns. , for printf. To add, use parenthesis. 
        System.out.println("\nInput integer value 1: "+ iNumber);
        System.out.println("Input integer value 2: "+ iNumber2);
        System.out.println("Input double value 1: "+ iDecimal);
        System.out.println("Input double value 2: "+ iDecimal2);

        System.out.println("\nInteger output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Adding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber + iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Subtracting ", iNumber2, " and ", iNumber, " = ", iNumber2 - iNumber);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Multiplying ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber * iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Division ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber / iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n\n", "Moding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber % iNumber2);

        System.out.println("Double output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Adding ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal + iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Subtracting ", iDecimal2, " and ", iDecimal, " = ", iDecimal2 - iDecimal);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Multiplying ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal * iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Dividing ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal / iDecimal2);
    }
    else if (iNumber2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("\nNumber 2 equals 0:");
        //+ instead of , for Printlns. , for printf. To add, use parenthesis. 
        System.out.println("\nInput integer value 1: "+ iNumber);
        System.out.println("Input integer value 2: "+ iNumber2);
        System.out.println("Input double value 1: "+ iDecimal);
        System.out.println("Input double value 2: "+ iDecimal2);

        System.out.println("\nInteger output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Adding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber + iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%n", "Subtracting ", iNumber, " = ", iNumber - iNumber2);
        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%n", "Multiplying ", iNumber, " = ", iNumber * iNumber2);

        if (iNumber2 == 0 || iDecimal2 == 0){
            System.out.println("Error: You cannot divide and mod by zero!!!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n", "Division ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber / iNumber2);
            System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%n\n", "Moding ", iNumber, " and ", iNumber2, " = ", iNumber % iNumber2);

        }

        System.out.println("Double output: ");
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Adding ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal + iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Subtracting ", iDecimal, " = ", iDecimal - iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Squaring ", iDecimal, " = ", iDecimal * iDecimal2);
        System.out.printf("%s%.2f%s%.2f%s%.2f%n", "Dividing ", iDecimal, " and ", iDecimal2, " = ", iDecimal / iDecimal2);
    }
    // a.   Test the two numbers, subtract the smaller number from the larger number.  Display the output with the numbers in the proper order.  If the numbers are equal, display a message that subtracting a number from itself gives you zero.

    // b.   If the two numbers are equal, the program should display the message as “Squaring” a number instead of multiplying two numbers.

    // c.   If the second number is zero, the program should display an error message saying that you cannot divide or mod by zero.



    // 7.   Using multiple printf statements, display the result of adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing the two double values.
    // a.   Test the two numbers, subtract the smaller number from the larger number.  Display the output with the numbers in the proper order. If the numbers are equal, display a message that subtracting a number from itself gives you zero.
    // b.   If the two numbers are equal, the program should display the message as “Squaring” a number instead of multiplying two numbers.
    // c.   If the second number is zero, the program should display an error message saying that you cannot divide by zero.
// 8.   Make sure that there is a title before each of the two outputs and there are blank lines between the input section and the two output sections.


// 9.   Ask the user if they wish to enter in another set of numbers.
count = input.nextInt(); 

    do {
        System.out.println("Do you wish to enter another set of numbers?: (y/n)");
        yesNo = input.next().charAt(0);
        // a.   The only valid entries are : y, Y, n or N (single letters)
        if (yesNo != 'Y' && yesNo != 'y' && yesNo != 'N' && yesNo != 'n') {
            System.out.println("Error = you must enter Y or N. Please retry. "); // Error message should be inside the if statement block or else the error message would always appear.    
        }

    } while (yesNo != 'Y' && yesNo != 'y' && yesNo != 'N' && yesNo != 'n');


}
}

System.out.print("Do you wish to enter another set of numbers?: (y/n)");
String answer = scan.nextLine();



    // b.   Use the Java construct input.next().charAt(0) to get the character value
    // c.   Place the input into a loop that tests the entry for validity
        // i.   If the entry is valid, end the loop
        // ii.  If the entry is invalid, display an error message and ask the user to reenter their response
// 10.  If the user indicated that they wish to enter new values, continue the loop and allow the user to reenter a new set of values.
    // a.   The user should be allowed to reenter values as many times as they like.  Only the entry of ‘n’ or ‘N’ should cause the loop to end.
// 11.  If the user indicated that they do not wish to enter any more values, end the loop and display a thank you/goodbye message.
// 12.  Comment your code.
```

//3) The program does not implement the new loop correctly.  The purpose of the loop was to allow the user to enter in their four numbers and do the math.
// The program should then ask the user if they want to continue, If they do, the program should allow the entry of four more numbers.
// The should continue until the user specifically says no they want to stop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DL1F.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUOx7.jpg)

Comment: Your code is one huge method.  I think you need to look at designing your code better, for example using Top Down design to break your code into smaller segments that can be more easily understood and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

This question is barely readable. You should try writing neater questions so more people will be able to assist you. Give a short portion of the code where the problem lies and ask "why is this incorrect?".

As for your question, I think you should have another while loop, which will include the logic you implemented. Something like `while(yesNo == 'Y' || yesNo == 'y')`. So while this is true, you read 4 inputs from the user. To me it seems like you don't even care if the user entered 'n' or 'y', your do-while loop merely checks input validity.

Comment: Hello, I'm completely new to Java so I have trouble asking questions about it correctly. I have no idea where the problem lies. We had a couple of snow days so the professor had to accelerate the class. Thank you for taking the time to make it easier for me to understand.